# Возможно ли адаптировать скин IPB c версии 2.2.x - 2.3.x под 3.2?

Tags: ipb

Здравствуйте, хочу использовать скин [Aurora 3 ( 2.2.x - 2.3.x)](http://www.xghozt.com/site/skins.php), но он, к сожалению, под старые версии. Там еще есть `Aurora 3: Red ( Premium Skin )`, но не понятно, для какой версии.

Стоит ли использовать `IPB` версии 2.2.x? (интересует не уязвим ли он)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совместимыми являются только стили v2.2.x и 2.3.x. Их шаблоны отличаются минимально, поэтому в простых стилях адаптация к нужной линейке форумов произойдет автоматически. Остальные стили, разработанные для разных версий IPB, несовместимы принципиально. Несмотря на небольшие внешние различия, в структуре их шаблонов участвуют разные входящие php-переменные, специфические для каждой конкретной линейки форумов.

По поводу уязвимости, во второй версии видимо их достаточно много, сходу нашёл несколько эксполйтов. Если важна безопасность рекомендую выбрать версию посвежее.